# zip file size limitation on ckan java client upload

Tags: java, file-upload, ckan

I have created a java program that can upload a file to a ckan installation, (currently my local testing installation, haven't tested it on a live one).
The text files that i tested my application are uploaded to ckan properly. I do have a problem with some zip files.
After some test and failure attempts, i realized that the problem is in the size of the file. For zip files less than 4Kb it works, but for larger files it fails with the error "server Error".
The files failing to upload via my java application, upload just fine when using the ckan front end, so i am guessing the problem is with my java application and not the ckan installation. This is the code I am using:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
File file = new File(uploadFileName);   

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new  SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String date=dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()); 

HttpPost postRequest;
try {
    ContentType zipType=ContentType.create("zip");
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file,zipType);
    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .addPart("file", cbFile)
            .addPart("url",new StringBody(HOST+"/files/"+date+"/"+uploadFileName,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("upload",cbFile)                
            .addPart("title",new StringBody(TITLE,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("description",new StringBody(DESCRIPTION+date,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("comment",new StringBody(COMMENT,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("key", new StringBody(uploadFileName+date,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("package_id",new StringBody("test2",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .addPart("notes", new StringBody("notes",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
             .build();
    postRequest = new HttpPost(HOST+"/api/action/resource_create");
    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
    postRequest.setHeader("X-CKAN-API-Key", myApiKey);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    }
catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
         } 
finally {
     httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
         }
```